# Can I save a HTML form data (including radio button) as a local txt file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

The code below works perfectly to download a text box. However, I wish to expand upon it to add three boxes and a radio button. I'd then like to be able to download the .txt containing all the data. For example, FirstName, Surname, Email, Male/Female(radio button).
I can't seem to find a way of doing this. Any help hugely appreciated!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
form * {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
</style>
<script language="Javascript" >
function download(filename, text) {
  var pom = document.createElement('a');
  pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + 

encodeURIComponent(text));
  pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

  pom.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(pom);

  pom.click();

  document.body.removeChild(pom);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form onsubmit="download(this['name'].value, this['text'].value)">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="test.txt">
  <textarea rows=3 cols=50 name="text">Please type in this box. When you 

click the Download button, the contents of this box will be downloaded to 

your machine at the location you specify. Pretty nifty. </textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Download">
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: You can add the radio button data data in the text before passing it to your download() function.

Comment: All you need to do is get all the data from the DOM. Add it together then format it .. then pass it to your download function.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values with getElementById if you set id's on each element as the pattern I'll did. Join them together with a line brake.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
form * {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
</style>
<script language="Javascript" >
function download(filename) {
  var inputArray = [];
  inputArray[0]='Firstname: '+document.getElementById('firstName').value;
  inputArray[1]='Lastname: '+document.getElementById('lastName').value;
  inputArray[2]='Text 1: '+document.getElementById('text1').value;
  inputArray[3]='Text 2: '+document.getElementById('text2').value;
  
  var text = inputArray.join('\n');
  
  var pom = document.createElement('a');
  pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + 

encodeURIComponent(text));
  pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

  pom.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(pom);

  pom.click();

  document.body.removeChild(pom);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form onsubmit="download(this['name'].value)">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="test.txt">
  <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="Firstname">
  <input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Lastname">
  <textarea rows=3 cols=50 id="text1"> First </textarea>
<textarea rows=3 cols=50 id="text2"> Second </textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Download">
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I think it is better to generate output content as JSON. That make data more readable.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        form * {
            display: block;
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <script language="Javascript">
        function download() {
            var text = document.getElementsByName('text')[0].value;
            var gender = document.getElementsByName('gender')[0].value;
            var email = document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value;
            var fileName = document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value;
            var obj = {
                text: text,
                gender: gender,
                email: email
            };
            var pom = document.createElement('a');
            pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj)));
            pom.setAttribute('download', fileName);
            pom.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(pom);
            pom.click();
            document.body.removeChild(pom);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <form onsubmit="return download()">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="test.txt">
        <textarea rows=3 cols=50 name="text">Please type in this box. When you 

click the Download button, the contents of this box will be downloaded to 

your machine at the location you specify. Pretty nifty. </textarea>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male"> Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="female"> Female
        <input type="submit" value="Download">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful!